# Archivo .class demasiado grande

Tags: android, kotlin, compilar

Tengo un archivo de kotlin con una función que retorna una lista de strings con 10,000 elementos, pero a la hora de compilar genera error, dice que el archivo  .class es demasiado grande. ¿Que puedo hacer? Gracias de antemano.

```
return listOf(
  "cadena 1",
  "cadena 2",
  ...
  "cadena 10,000"
)
```

cada cadena tiene entre 5 y 20 caracteres mas o menos.

error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error generating class file
path/../LiveLiterals$FileName.cass (compile from [path..]) 
class to large
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega mas información, por favor revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, si retorna una lista de strings con 10,000 elementos no tiene que ver con el tamaño del archivo .class, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo siento pero no puedo ayudarte para que el compilador te acepte la clase tal como la tienes escrita.

Puedes intentar poner las cadenas en algún tipo de fichero de texto, ya sea texto plano o xml, y que la clase lea dicho fichero al ejecutar la aplicación.

Esto además te dará la flexibilidad de poder cambiar las cadenas sin tener que recompilar.